# Delay for customs in and out of Canadian airports?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, transit, canada

I am traveling to Granada via Toronto. I live in Michigan and the best flight available was out of Toronto, plus I figured I could explore the city a little before I go. However, I've never really flown internationally so I'm not sure if that adds overhead while transitioning between flights.

I have Toronto(YYZ) -> Miami(MIA) arriving 934AM. Then Miami departing for Grenada(GND) at 10:55AM.

As a US citizen with a passport, will I have to go through any customs for the flight Toronto->Miami->Grenada? If so will 1.5 hours be enough to clear it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will go through [United States border preclearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_border_preclearance) in Toronto Pearson International Airport before boarding your first flight to Miami.  Thus, you will not normally have to undergo any border procedures upon arrival in Miami.  Be sure to check-in at the Toronto airport well in advance, in order to allow time for the preclearance.

Comment: And don't forget to factor in the possibility of delays in crossing the land border into Canada from the United States.